# Распарсить string регуляркой на руби

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Есть переменная с кучей строк, хочу получить значение `123123123` в отдельной переменной, пишу:

```ruby
out = "app_ver = 1.4.8
arp_inspection = 123123123
arp_inspection_errors = 0
clients_count = 0
ip_guard_errors = 0
non_client_bw_limit_down = 5242880
non_client_bw_limit_up = 5242880
session_unauth_count = 0
sessions_count = 0
start_time = 1454235448"

out.each_line do |line|
    if (line =~ /[arp_inspection]*([0-9])/) then
        arp_inspection = line
    end
end
print arp_inspection
```

Что я делаю не так? Как мне вытащить оттуда значение arp_inspection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out = "app_ver = 1.4.8
arp_inspection = 0
arp_inspection_errors = 0
clients_count = 0
ip_guard_errors = 0
non_client_bw_limit_down = 5242880
non_client_bw_limit_up = 5242880
session_unauth_count = 0
sessions_count = 0
start_time = 1454235448"
arp_inspection = "123123123"
out.each_line do |line|
    line = line.chomp
    if (line =~ /^arp_inspection =.*([0-9])/) then
        print $1, "\n"
        arp_inspection = $1
    end
end
print  arp_inspection
```

Comment: Подскажите, это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky, это я уже нашёл решение. Таким способом работает. Ошибка была в регулярке.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать прямым присваиванием переменной значения изнутри `Regexp`-а:

```
/^arp_inspection =.*(?<arp_inspection>[0-9])/ =~ line
# arp_inspection => 123123123
```

Заметьте, главное не менять `Regexp` и строку местами, иначе присваивания не произойдёт, и работает это только для руби 1.9.1 и выше, если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score -1):

В переменной не "куча строк", а одна строка, но с наличием символов перевода строки (`\n`). Поэтому достается рез-тат не циклом, а одной операцией:

```
arp_inspection = out[/^arp_inspection = (\d*)/, 1]
```